# Use for loop in Oracle SQL developer

Tags: sql, oracle

The following code gives me this error

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
>   00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:
>   Error at Line: 26 Column: 1

```
for i in (7,14,21,28,35) 
loop
  Select CODE_ACCOUNTING_METHOD,
         trunc(sysdate-i, 'iw')           as week_report,
         sum(ELI_12MOB)                   as eligible_client,
         sum(client)                      as total_client,
         (sum(ELI_12MOB)/sum(client))*100 as eligible_rate
   from  pm_eli_base
   where week_start = trunc(sysdate-(360+i), 'iw')
     and code_accounting_method != 'CL'
   group by CODE_ACCOUNTING_METHOD, trunc(sysdate-i, 'iw')
   union all
   select 'Total', 
           trunc(sysdate-i, 'iw') as week_report,
           sum(ELI_12MOB)         as eligible_client,
           sum(client)            as total_client,
           (sum(ELI_12MOB)/sum(client))*100
     from pm_eli_base
    where week_start = trunc(sysdate-(360+i), 'iw')
      and code_accounting_method != 'CL'
    group by 'Total', trunc(sysdate-i, 'iw')
end loop;
```

Please help me with this case

[This is the result I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPKIJ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using SQLDeveloper, you can declare your query in a cursor and call your cursor on select values of `i`

```
DECLARE 

CURSOR code_accounting_method(i number)
is
Select CODE_ACCOUNTING_METHOD,
         trunc(sysdate-i, 'iw')           as week_report,
         sum(ELI_12MOB)                   as eligible_client,
         sum(client)                      as total_client,
         (sum(ELI_12MOB)/sum(client))*100 as eligible_rate
   from  pm_eli_base
   where week_start = trunc(sysdate-(360+i), 'iw')
     and code_accounting_method != 'CL'
   group by CODE_ACCOUNTING_METHOD, trunc(sysdate-i, 'iw')
   union all
   select 'Total', 
           trunc(sysdate-i, 'iw') as week_report,
           sum(ELI_12MOB)         as eligible_client,
           sum(client)            as total_client,
           (sum(ELI_12MOB)/sum(client))*100
     from pm_eli_base
    where week_start = trunc(sysdate-(360+i), 'iw')
      and code_accounting_method != 'CL'
    group by 'Total', trunc(sysdate-i, 'iw');

 cam_record  CODE_ACCOUNTING_METHOD%rowtype;

BEGIN

        for i in 1 .. 35 loop
          if i in (7,14,21,28,35) then
                open code_accounting_method(i);
                fetch code_accounting_method into  cam_record;
                close code_accounting_method;
               --Now report the fields that are in cam_record;
               -- such as 
              dbms_output.put_line(cam_record.week_report);

          end if;
        end loop;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you missed `;` at the end of the query.

Second what are you trying to achieve by select query? Use `INTO` to assign values to some variable.

Update:
You can use following technique apart from what @btpys suggested.

```
FOR J IN 1..5 LOOP
I := J*7;
...
...
END LOOP;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: i have added the result that i want to achieve

Answer (score 1):

You can't do:

```
for i in (7,14,21,28,35)
```

do:

```
SQL> 
declare
   type nt_type is table of number;
   nt nt_type := nt_type (7,14,21,28,35);
begin
for i in 1..nt.count loop
   dbms_output.put_line(nt(i));
end loop;
end;
/

7
14
21
28
35

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: thanks bro, it gives me this error when I put the select statement into the loop     
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 6, column 1:
PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Comment: As Tejash said, you need to assign the results of your query into variables with the INTO clause.

Answer (score 0):

I think a `for` loop is the wrong tool.
You should create a view, and use `union all` and copy and paste and replace the `i` by the values 7,14,21,28,35 in the selects manually. So that you have a view with a `union all` 5x2 times = 10 select statements.

Comment: I was doing exactly that, but I thought it didnt look so clean lol